# Snowplow Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stopping-times

A snowplow can remove snow at a constant rate (in cubic feet per minute). One day, there was no snow on the ground at sunrise, but sometime in the morning it began snowing at a steady rate. At noon, the plow began to remove snow. It had cleared 2 miles of snow between noon and 1 PM, and 1 more mile of snow between 1 PM and 2 PM. At what time did it start snowing?

My problem with this problem is clarity. When it says the snow is removed at a rate of cubic feet per minute, how does that convert to MILES of snow removed? There is a dimensional confusion here and it is making it difficult for me to understand this problem .

i would be interest for any replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** The first sentence tells you that the snowplow can remove a certain number of cubic feet of snow per minute. This means that as the depth of the snow increases, the snowplow drives slower and covers less distance. In particular, you can assume that the speed of the snowplow is *inversely proportional* to the depth of the snow.

Have fun!

Comment: Is there a sleek way to show that the speed of the snowplow is inversely proportional to the depth of the snow?

Comment: It follows immediately from the given fact that a fixed volume $V$ of snow is removed per minute. If $w$ is the width of the blade, $v$ is the velocity, and $d$ is the depth of snow, this means that $(v\Delta t)wd = V\Delta t$, so $vd=\text{constant}$.